# XPath OR operator on multiple different elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, automated-tests, element, specflow

I have two elements that cannot be on the same page together. I want to make one Xpath Selector that checks for either Element A, OR element B:

```
Element A: //div[contains(@class, 'A')]//button[@name='Name123']

Element B: //div[contains(@class, 'B')]//button[@name='Name123']
```

I thought it would work something in the line of

```
("(//div[contains(@class, 'A')]//button[@name='Name123']) OR 
(//div[contains(@class, 'B')]//button[@name='Name123'])")
```

But that is not a valid XPath expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only reason it's invalid is that `OR` should be `or`. But it can be written a lot more concisely. And also (although you don't make this clear) it looks as if you want the `div` that satisfies some condition, not a boolean result that tells you whether such a `div` exists.

Comment: Does `//button[@name='Name123']` by itself not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'A') or contains(@class, 'B')]//button[@name='Name123']
```

Comment: And a bit more concise (and perhaps efficient) would be `//div[@class[contains(., 'A') or contains(., 'B')]]//button[@name='Name123']`

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of extra bracers and replace OR with | then it is going to happen.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'A')]//button[@name='Name123'] | //div[contains(@class, 'B')]//button[@name='Name123']"));
```

Comment: That's stellar! Thanks for your quick response. Both your option and SRK's work brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if there are many `div` elements whose class contains 'A' or 'B', but few `button` elements whose `@name` is 'Name123', then the following may be more efficient:

```
//button[@name='Name123'][ancestor::div[@class[contains(.,'A') or contains(., 'B')]]
```

But of course this is implementation-dependent.